# We already working on the project - We are already working on the project?

Tags: grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs

Which sentence is correct?

> We already working on the project
>
> We are already working on the project

?

Answer (score 2):

"We working on the project" is not a grammatical sentence in most varieties of English, as it does not have a finite verb.

Therefore "We already working on the project" is equally ungrammatical in most varieties of English.